Reusable SwiftUI View API with and without data, like List
I've been trying to create a reusable SwiftUI View API that takes an optional RandomAccessCollection arg, and output accordingly, like List does. For example...
MyContainer(things) { thing in
    Text("\(thing.name)")
}

MyContainer {
    Text("\(thingA.name)")
    Text("\(thingB.name)")
}

I understand child @ViewBuilder parameters and I think I have the initialization down via parametric polymorphism (where Data: RandomAccessCollection, ... and where Data == Never, ...) except I've been pulling my hair out trying to return a different var body: some View result depending on whether data was provided.

You should not "return a different body depending on whether data is provided". You should "unify" the two cases in the initialisers.
Look at how List is implemented - List has 2 type parameters, SelectionValue (which I will not consider) and Content. When you use the data-less initialiser, Content is set to whatever view you provide. When you use some data to populate the list, the Content is set to ForEach<Data, Data.Element.ID, RowContent>.
Here are the signatures of the two initialisers:
init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content)

init<Data, RowContent>(
    _ data: Data,
    @ViewBuilder rowContent: @escaping (Data.Element) -> RowContent
) where Content == ForEach<Data, Data.Element.ID, RowContent>, Data : RandomAccessCollection, RowContent : View, Data.Element : Identifiable

Notice the Content == ForEach<...> constraint on the second initialiser.
So you should just do the same:
struct CustomList<Content: View>: View {
    let content: Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }

    init<Data, RowContent>(
        _ data: Data,
        @ViewBuilder rowContent: @escaping (Data.Element) -> RowContent
    ) where Content == ForEach<Data, Data.Element.ID, RowContent>, Data : RandomAccessCollection, RowContent : View, Data.Element : Identifiable {
        content = ForEach(data, content: rowContent)
    }

    var body: some View { ... }
}

Now body is trivial - just use content, regardless of which initialiser the user called. If you want to extract each subview the user passed, use ForEach(subviewOf:) as malhal suggested.
If you are using a lower iOS version, you can still use View Extractor. For example, you can arrange the subviews vertically, and add a yellow background and some padding to each subview:
var body: some View {
    VStack {
      //ForEach(subviewOf: content) { view in
        ExtractMulti(content) { view in
            view
                .background(.yellow)
                .padding()
        }
    }
}


Excellent! Wrapping the data and child content during the init is what I was missing. I was fruitlessly trying to do that in the body. Thank you!

You can use @ViewBuilder and  ForEach(subviewOf:content:) for that, e.g.
struct MyContainer<Content: View>: View {

  @ViewBuilder var content: Content

  var body: some View {
    ForEach(subviewOf: content) { subview in
      subview
    }
  }
}

See Demystify SwiftUI containers WWDC 2024 at 3:30 for more info.

Thanks for the comment, but as mentioned above, I wasn't having an issue with child view content. My issue was in resolving two outcomes; one with data and one without. Sorry, I wasn't more clear.

Oh the presenter in the video mentioned this exact feature of List so I assumed their code sample would do the same, strange they didn’t implement it.
